# Using sed with a newline in a regex

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed, newline

I'm bashing my head against the wall with this one. How do I do a regex replacement with `sed` on text that contains a newline?

I need to replace the value of the "version" XML element shown below. There are multiple version elements so I want to replace the one that comes after the "name" element.

```
<name>MyName</name>
<version>old</version>
```

Here's my command:

```
sed -i -E "s@(\s*<name>$NAME</name>\n\s*<version>)$VERSION_OLD(</version>)@\1$VERSION_NEW\2@g" $myfile.txt
```

Now as far as I know there is a way to make `sed` work with a newline character, but I can't figure it out. I've already used sed in my script so ideally I'd prefer to re-use it instead of say `perl`.

Comment: The solution is to use a tool designed for working with XML, not sed!

Comment: Is there a decent standard Bash tool for parsing and manipulating XML? This is part of a larger Bash script...

Comment: Regarding parsing XML with regex, see [the famous post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/675568).

Comment: I'm not aware of any tool that would provide you with a one-line solution - perhaps it's worth looking at a solution in a language such as perl or python. Alternatively there's always good ol' XSLT :)

Answer (score 3):

When you see your `name` element, you will need to use the `N` command to read the next line:

file:

```
<bar>MyName</bar>
<version>old</version>
<name>MyName</name>
<version>old</version>
<foo>MyName</foo>
<version>old</version>
```

With GNU sed:

```
sed '/<name>/{N;s/old/newer/}' file
```

Output:

```
<bar>MyName</bar>
<version>old</version>
<name>MyName</name>
<version>new</version>
<foo>MyName</foo>
<version>old</version>
```

Comment: If the `name` element might also contain `old`, you'll want something a bit more robust, such as `N;P;s/.*\n//;s/old/newer/`

Comment: Thank you. Or replace in my version `N` by `n`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using GNU sed, you can use its extended addressing syntax:

```
sed '/<name>/,+1{/<version>/s/old/newer/}' file
```

Breaking this down, it says: for a line matching `<name>` and the following line (`+1`), then if the line matches `<version>`, substitute `old` with `newer`.

I'm assuming here that your file is generated, and will always have the `name` and `version` elements each on a single line, and adjacent.  If you need to handle more free-form XML, then you should really consider an XPath-based tool rather than sed.